# Why does accessing Ajax response variable crash code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following client script that makes a successful Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Register?handler=GeneratePassword",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var resp = response;
        var pwd = response.password;
        if (response.ok === true) {
            $("#genPwd").val(response.password);
        }
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

When I put a break-point on the line:

```
var resp = response;
```

Then `resp` is `{ok: true, password: "OkF6"}`. When I try and execute the following line:

```
var pwd = response.password;
```

the function just exits, no error, no exception, nothing. It just stops completely. What is wrong with this Ajax code of mine?

Comment: Use the brower's dev tools, add a breakpoint on the code (or add a `debugger;` line inside the soccess callback) and manually run that line to see if there's an error, go step by step to check each line. It should just work, I guess there's something elsge going on that's not related to taht code.

Comment: try to `console.log(typeof response)`, chances are it is `string`. In that case you need to parse it to JSON (See @Shahzeb's answer). If it is a string, then `response.ok` is undefined, so the `if` is skipped and the function ends.

Answer (score 1):

Parse your response to `json` object before accessing the value.

```
var resp = JSON.parse(response);
```